# Eliminate NULL fields from merged joins resultset

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, null

I created following view "user_details_merged":

```
SELECT DISTINCT
coalesce(own.user_name, join_user_name.user_name) AS user_name,
coalesce(own.email, join_mail.email) AS email,
coalesce(own.first_name, join_name.first_name) AS first_name,
coalesce(own.last_name, join_name.last_name) AS last_name
FROM
user_details AS own

LEFT JOIN user_details AS join_user_name ON 
    own.user_name IS NULL AND (
    (join_user_name.email = own.email AND own.email IS NOT NULL) 
    OR (join_user_name.first_name = own.first_name AND join_user_name.last_name = own.last_name 
    AND own.first_name IS NOT NULL AND own.last_name IS NOT NULL))


LEFT JOIN user_details AS join_mail ON 
    own.email IS NULL AND (
    (join_mail.user_name = own.user_name AND own.user_name IS NOT NULL) 
    OR (join_mail.first_name = own.first_name AND join_mail.last_name = own.last_name 
    AND own.first_name IS NOT NULL AND own.last_name IS NOT NULL))

LEFT JOIN user_details AS join_name ON 
    own.first_name IS NULL AND own.last_name IS NULL AND (
    (join_name.email = own.email AND own.email IS NOT NULL) 
    OR (join_name.user_name = own.user_name AND own.user_name IS NOT NULL))

ORDER BY user_name ASC,email ASC, first_name ASC, last_name ASC
```

This merges my columns from:

```
user_name | email | first_name | last_name
a             b       NULL         NULL
NULL          b        c            d
a            NULL      e            f
NULL          x        y            z
```

to

```
user_name | email | first_name | last_name
a             b       NULL         NULL
NULL          b        c            d
a            NULL      e            f
NULL          x        y            z

a             b        c            d
a             b        e            f
```

what i want is:

```
user_name | email | first_name | last_name
NULL          x        y            z
a             b        c            d
a             b        e            f
```

without the NULL containing ROWS when there is a row with the same data having more information, but still keep the /NULL          x        y            z/ when there is no other row with more information.

This second view here does exactly what i need:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.user_name,a.email,a.first_name,a.last_name FROM
user_details_merged a
LEFT JOIN user_details_merged b
ON
(
    (
    a.user_name IS NOT NULL OR 
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT user_name FROM user_details_merged b WHERE b.user_name IS NOT NULL AND 
        b.email=ISNULL(a.email,b.email) AND 
        b.first_name=isnull(a.first_name,b.first_name) AND
        b.last_name=isnull(a.last_name,b.last_name))
    )

    AND

    (
    a.email IS NOT NULL OR 
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT email FROM user_details_merged b WHERE b.email IS NOT NULL AND 
        b.user_name=ISNULL(a.user_name,b.user_name) AND 
        b.first_name=isnull(a.first_name,b.first_name) AND
        b.last_name=isnull(a.last_name,b.last_name))
    )

    AND

    (
    (a.first_name IS NOT NULL AND a.last_name IS NOT NULL) OR 
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT email FROM user_details_merged b WHERE b.email IS NOT NULL AND 
        b.user_name=ISNULL(a.user_name,b.user_name) AND 
        b.email=ISNULL(a.email,b.email))
        -- AND b.first_name=isnull(a.first_name,b.first_name) AND b.last_name=isnull(a.last_name,b.last_name))
    )

    AND NOT (a.first_name = b.first_name AND a.last_name = b.last_name AND a.email = b.email AND a.user_name = b.user_name)

)

WHERE coalesce(b.user_name,b.email,b.first_name,b.last_name) IS NOT NULL
```

The main problem is that the user_details view, where the data is coming from consists of many unions of different tables. Some containing only username & email and some only email and first name/last name etc. That's why there is no unique key and i'm not able to Index the View because of the UNIONS. That makes it impossible to execute the last view in under an hour.
My current workaround is a procedure, that stores the data of the user_details_merged view in a temp table and let the second view above use the data from this table. That way i can reduce the execution time to 7 seconds for 8000 rows.

Any other suggestions?

Thank you very much ;)

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your question. What GROUP BY MAX column? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Hi. You can eliminate rows containing NULL by SELECT MAX(user_name),email,MAX(first_name),MAX(last_name) .. GROUP BY email. But that would elimanate all rows containing user_name = NULL or eliminate different results for one user_name

Comment: It looks like you are trying to de-dupe information. The big question is to figure out what your id is. From what I can see and have seen, the email is the common denominator. Is there a reason you are not using that as a key?

Comment: @Heidi Yes it's some kind of de-dupe. More like a de-redundancy. Please check out the edit i made above. There are many duplicates in every column. None of them could be a unique key. Sadly i have to work on merged tables from 3rd Parties. I would never create such a horrible table structure ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ouch!  That's a messy data model.  The best solution would be to fix the data model to prevent the need for such a complex query.  However, that tends to be even more complicated with application dependencies, so I'm going to assume that has already been entertained.

- I used the 4 row sample to come up with an alternative solution.
- Then I added a couple of rows with only First and Last name values, which exposed a missed scenario in the query above.
- I also replicated the same 6 rows into over 12K rows, since the data model appears to support such a scenario.  This ended up causing the above query to run for over 2 hours before I finally just gave up and stopped it.
- I ran the 12K rows against my solution, and it returned in less than a second with the expected results.

So, without further adieu:

```
-- =================================================================================
-- BEGIN: SETUP TEST DATA
-- =================================================================================
SET NOCOUNT ON 

IF OBJECT_ID('user_details', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE user_details;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.user_details (
    user_name   char(1) NULL,
    email       char(1) NULL,
    first_name  char(1) NULL,
    last_name   char(1) NULL
)
GO

INSERT dbo.user_details
SELECT * 
  FROM (
        SELECT * FROM dbo.user_details WHERE 1=2
        UNION ALL SELECT 'a',   'b',    NULL,   NULL
        UNION ALL SELECT NULL,  'b',    'c',    'd'
        UNION ALL SELECT 'a',   NULL,   'e',    'f'
        UNION ALL SELECT NULL,  'x',    'y',    'z'
        UNION ALL SELECT NULL,  NULL,   'y',    'z'
        UNION ALL SELECT NULL,  NULL,   'a',    'z'
       ) A
GO

--/*
-- TURN 6 ROWS INTO OVER 12K ROWS TO TEST PERFORMANCE
DECLARE @count int; SELECT @count = 0
WHILE @count < 11
  BEGIN 
    INSERT user_details
    SELECT * 
      FROM user_details

    SELECT @count = @count + 1
END
--*/
-- =================================================================================
-- END: SETUP TEST DATA
-- =================================================================================


-- =================================================================================
-- BEGIN: NEW SOLUTION FINAL: <1sec on 12288 rows
-- =================================================================================
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#useremail', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #useremail;
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#email', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #email;
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#user', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #user;
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#name', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #name;


-- GET YOUR UNIQUE user_name AND email KEY
SELECT DISTINCT A.user_name, A.email
  INTO #useremail
  FROM user_details A


-- GET YOUR UNIQUE email VALUES
SELECT DISTINCT A.email, A.first_name, A.last_Name
  INTO #email
  FROM user_details A
 WHERE A.email IS NOT NULL


-- GET YOUR UNIQUE user_name VALUES
SELECT DISTINCT A.user_name, A.first_name, A.last_Name
  INTO #user
  FROM user_details A
 WHERE A.user_name IS NOT NULL


-- GET YOUR UNIQUE first_name AND last_Name VALUES NOT PART OF THE KEY
SELECT DISTINCT A.first_name, A.last_Name
  INTO #name
  FROM user_details A
 WHERE A.first_name IS NOT NULL
   AND A.last_Name IS NOT NULL
   AND A.user_name IS NULL
   AND A.email IS NULL


-- CLEAN UP YOUR UNIQUE user_name AND email KEY
DELETE A
-- SELECT *
  FROM #useremail A
  JOIN (
        SELECT *
          FROM #useremail
         WHERE user_name IS NOT NULL
           AND email IS NOT NULL
       ) B
    ON (A.user_name = B.user_name AND A.email     IS NULL)
    OR (A.email     = B.email     AND A.user_name IS NULL)


-- CLEAN UP YOUR UNIQUE email VALUES
DELETE A
-- SELECT *
  FROM #email A
  JOIN (
        SELECT *
          FROM #email
         WHERE first_name IS NOT NULL
           AND last_Name IS NOT NULL
       ) B
    ON A.email = B.email
   AND A.first_name IS NULL
   AND A.last_name IS NULL


-- CLEAN UP YOUR UNIQUE user_name VALUES
DELETE A
-- SELECT *
  FROM #user A
  JOIN (
        SELECT *
          FROM #user
         WHERE first_name IS NOT NULL
           AND last_Name IS NOT NULL
       ) B
    ON A.user_name = B.user_name
   AND A.first_name IS NULL
   AND A.last_name IS NULL


-- CLEAN UP YOUR UNIQUE #name VALUES
DELETE A
-- SELECT *
  FROM #name A
  JOIN #user B
    ON A.first_name = B.first_name
   AND A.last_name  = B.last_name

DELETE A
-- SELECT *
  FROM #name A
  JOIN #email B
    ON A.first_name = B.first_name
   AND A.last_name  = B.last_name


-- GET YOUR DATA
SELECT A.user_name
      ,A.email
      ,U.first_name
      ,U.last_name
      --,*
  FROM #useremail A
  JOIN #user U
    ON A.user_name = U.user_name
 UNION 
SELECT A.user_name
      ,A.email
      ,E.first_name
      ,E.last_name
      --,*
  FROM #useremail A
  JOIN #email E
    ON A.email = E.email
 UNION 
SELECT NULL as [user_name]
      ,NULL as [email]
      ,N.first_name
      ,N.last_name
      --,*
  FROM #name N
-- =================================================================================
-- END: NEW SOLUTION FINAL
-- =================================================================================
```

Comment: +1 for doing the ddl and data, have you heard of sqlfiddle.com?

Comment: Thanks for mentioning sqlfiddle.com.  It looks like a pretty useful little tool.

Answer (score 0):

-- If I get is right this time you can solve it by using following:

```
 SELECT ISNULL(A.USER_NAME, B.USER_NAME), A.EMAIL, A.FIRST_NAME, A.LAST_NAME FROM
 user_details A CROSS JOIN user_details B
 WHERE A.EMAIL IS NOT NULL
 AND A.FIRST_NAME IS NOT NULL
 AND A.LAST_NAME IS NOT NULL
 GROUP BY ISNULL(A.USER_NAME, B.USER_NAME), A.EMAIL, A.FIRST_NAME, A.LAST_NAME
```

Comment: sorry but it doesn't work that way. i still get "NULL          b        c            d" even though there is "a          b        c            d"  :/ and i would have to check that for every column

Answer (score 0):

try using an outer join against user_details.